# How to process a file in correct encoding in powershell?

Tags: mysql, powershell, encoding, utf-8, cmd

I have a `MySQL`'s `SQL` file which is encoded in `UTF8` called `data.sql` (which is produced by the `mysqldump` command).

1. If I run the following in a `cmd.exe` console the file is correctly processed.

   ```
   mysql --defaults-file=mysql.update2.ini --batch --raw --database=test1 --default-character-set=utf8 < "data.sql"
   ```
2. If I run the following in a `powershell` console the data are inserted in wrong encoding (resulting in `??` instead of characters with diacritics).

   ```
   Get-Content "data.sql" | & 'mysql' --defaults-file=mysql.update2.ini --batch --raw --database=test1 --default-character-set=utf8
   ```
3. If I run the same from Powershell ISE, the script is imported with correct encoding.

How to fix the `powershell` script so the SQL file is processed such that the characters with diacritics are correctly inserted if run as a `powershell` script (using a `powershell` console)?

I have tried to set `-Encoding` parameter of `Get-Content` to `UTF8`, `ASCII`, `Unicode` or `OEM` but neither of them resulted in the correctly imported data.

Notes

- The `chcp` in the `cmd.exe` console returns `852`, the same for the `powershell` console as well as for the Powershell ISE.
- The `SQL` script contains lines describing intended encoding like `/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;`
- In both cases the `mysql.update2.ini` file contains `host`, `port`, `user` and `password` settings only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell ISE outputs in `iso-8859-1` and console in `us-ascii`
At least on my PC, you can check this yourself by checking the variable `$OutputEncoding`

You can change this variable

```
$OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

Then it should work in both Powershell ISE and Powershell Console

Comment: I have ISE in `windows-1250` and console in `us-ascii`. After setting `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1250)` it imports as expected.